# Google Calendar to Google Sheet integration

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I help with scheduling for a post-secondary first aid team. We schedule students 7 days a week from 9am-9pm and 9pm-9am on a google calendar, and we use google sheets to keep track of how many shifts they have done on which day/night.

I was wondering if it would be possible to populate this google sheet, whenever we add a student to the calendar for their shift. So say I add Student A on October 31st (Monday), can I make the process of adding 1 to the total shifts they have done on a monday day automatic? (I have some coding knowledge)

See:
[image: Google sheet that I wish to populate]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. (I haven't tried it though)

You may use `getEvents()` methods from [Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/?csw=1) to get all events that occur within a given time frame.

Then, as suggested by @teatimer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466885/import-google-or-ical-calendar-data-into-a-google-spreadsheet), your range has to match the size of the values array in both columns and rows when setting the values on a range.

To help you on the implementation, kindly check these SO posts:

- [Import google calendar data into existing google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843275/import-google-calendar-data-into-existing-google-spreadsheet)
- [Import Google or iCal calendar data into a google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466885/import-google-or-ical-calendar-data-into-a-google-spreadsheet).

You may want to also check this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/vafmjAoMdqg) and try the given option too.